# How to query on tables from a file list

Tags: sql, oracle

we have a list of 100 tables on which we need to find if its compressed or not, is there a way in which i can input this 100 tables names on a file and call it with a sql query, something like,

```
select 
  compression 
from 
  dba_tables 
where 
  table_name ...
```

and then give the file name which has this list of tables.

Comment: Your question needs to be made clearer. Tell us what you want to achieve, and show us what code you've tried.

Comment: Why can't you simply input the filename's in a `IN` clause?

Comment: What tool are you using to run the query?  SQL*Plus potentially has different options than, say, if you're using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your list into a table ("my_list") and then join to dba_tables.  Something like:

```
with compressed_tables as (
    select owner, table_name, tablespace_name
    from dba_tables
    where compression = 'ENABLED'
)
select c.table_name
from compressed_tables c, my_list l
where c.table_name = l.table_name
order by 1;
```

---

**Update:**

If you wanted to use a copy/pasted list of table names, you could certainly use that in a query (without loading into a separate table).  Just single quote the table names separated with a comma:

```
select table_name
from dba_tables
where compression = 'ENABLED'
and table_name IN (
'TABLE_A',
'TABLE_B',
'TABLE_C'
);
```

Comment: with the IN clause will i have to type in manually the 100 table names or can i use a file as an input

Comment: this is error i am getting, is my syntax wrong for the IN clause

Comment: SQL> select COMPRESSION from dba_tables where table_name in ("/oracle/EWD/abc") ;
select COMPRESSION from dba_tables where table_name in ("/oracle/EWD/abc")
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "/oracle/EWD/abc": invalid identifier


SQL> !more abc
USR02
USR03
USR04

Comment: Instead of a static table, I would rather implement a GTT(global temporary table) to store the table names. But it is just too much of work against the option of getting the table_names from the OS directory based file itself via shell script or batch.

Answer (score 0):

You **MUST** mention your OS details.

*For example*, if your OS is ***NIX**, in your shell script you just need to loop over table names from the list and pass them as parameter to an anonymous block, for which you would just open a sqlplus connection.

For **Windows OS**, you can have a batch file having the table_names list at a particular location, and then it would just invoke the underlying script.

Comment: thx lalit, i dont have a shell script yet, was just using a sql statement with the IN clause .

Comment: Hitting the DB tables is not good, so better use those table names directly from OS files.

Comment: would you have a sample of a unix script, we are on Solaris 10

Comment: Just Google for "how to loop over each value of a file in *nix".